how to fix open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
i am getting W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JayTN24/mens_shirt_0.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) public void shareWallpaper  i have send image wattsapp i could not send wattsapp EACCES (Permission denied) Errors are coming
How can I fix this problem?
EACCES (Permission denied)
package com.jaytn24.shopping.activities;

import static com.jaytn24.shopping.config.AppConfig.RTL_MODE;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.BANNER_RECIPE_DETAIL;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.BASE_IMAGE_URL;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.DELAY_SET;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.INTERSTITIAL_ON_RECIPES_LIST;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.NATIVE_AD_RECIPES_DETAIL;
import static com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant.SHARE;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.R;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.adapters.AdapterImage;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.adapters.AdapterSuggested;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.callbacks.CallbackRecipeDetail;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.callbacks.CallbackUser;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.config.AppConfig;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.databases.prefs.AdsPref;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.databases.prefs.SharedPref;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.databases.sqlite.DbHandler;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.models.Images;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.models.Recipe;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.models.User;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.models.Value;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.rests.ApiInterface;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.rests.RestAdapter;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.AdsManager;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.AppBarLayoutBehavior;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Constant;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.Tools;
import com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.jaytn24.shopping.utils.wallpaperHelper;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ActivityRecipeDetail1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private long recipe_id;
    private Call<CallbackRecipeDetail> callbackCall = null;
    private LinearLayout lyt_main_content;
    private Recipe post;

    MyApplication myApplication;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityRecipeDetail1";
    Button button8;
    TextView txt_recipe_title, txt_category, txt_recipe_time, txt_total_views,txtCommentText,txtCommentCount,price,discountprice;
    LinearLayout lyt_view,btnView,btnComment;
    ImageView thumbnail_video;
    private WebView recipe_description;
    DbHandler databaseHandler;
    CoordinatorLayout parent_view;
    private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
    RelativeLayout lyt_suggested;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe_refresh;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    ImageButton image_favorite;

    public Button btn_share;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    AdsPref adsPref;
    AdsManager adsManager;
    Call<CallbackUser> callbackCall2 = null;
    User user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Tools.getTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail1);
        Tools.getLayoutDirections(this, RTL_MODE);
        myApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        price = findViewById(R.id.price);
        discountprice = findViewById(R.id.discountprice);

        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
        adsPref = new AdsPref(this);
        databaseHandler = new DbHandler(this);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(new AppBarLayoutBehavior());

        adsManager = new AdsManager(this);
        adsManager.loadBannerAd(BANNER_RECIPE_DETAIL);
        adsManager.loadInterstitialAd(INTERSTITIAL_ON_RECIPES_LIST, adsPref.getInterstitialAdInterval());
        adsManager.loadNativeAd(NATIVE_AD_RECIPES_DETAIL);

        swipe_refresh = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipe_refresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        swipe_refresh.setRefreshing(false);
        txtCommentText = findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_text);

        lyt_main_content = findViewById(R.id.lyt_main_content);
        lyt_shimmer = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        parent_view = findViewById(R.id.lyt_content);

        thumbnail_video = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_video);
        txt_recipe_title = findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
        txt_category = findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        txt_recipe_time = findViewById(R.id.recipe_time);
        recipe_description = findViewById(R.id.recipe_description);
        txt_total_views = findViewById(R.id.total_views);
        lyt_view = findViewById(R.id.lyt_view_count);
        btnView = findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        image_favorite = findViewById(R.id.img_favorite);
        btn_share = findViewById(R.id.Order);
        btnComment = findViewById(R.id.btn_comment);

        lyt_suggested = findViewById(R.id.lyt_suggested);

        post = (Recipe) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC);
        txtCommentCount = findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_count);
        

        requestAction();

//        requestmenu();
        requestPostApi2();

        btnComment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityComments3.class);
            intent.putExtra("recipe_id", post.recipe_id);
            intent.putExtra("count", post.comments_count);
            intent.putExtra("post_title", post.recipe_title);
            startActivity(intent);

        });

        if (!sharedPref.getLoginFeature().equals("yes")) {
            btnComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtCommentText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            btnComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtCommentText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            lyt_shimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_shimmer.startShimmer();
            lyt_main_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            requestAction();
        });

        initToolbar();
        initFavorite();
        loadViewed();

    }


    private void requestAction() {
        showFailedView(false, "");
        swipeProgress(true);
        new Handler().postDelayed(this::requestPostData, 200);
    }

   

    public void displayData(final Recipe post) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            if (post.comments_count == 0) {
                txtCommentText.setText(R.string.txt_no_comment);
            }
            if (post.comments_count == 1) {
                txtCommentText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_read) + " " + post.comments_count + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.txt_comment));
            } else if (post.comments_count > 1) {
                txtCommentText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_read) + " " + post.comments_count + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.txt_comments));
            }
        }, 1500);
        txtCommentCount.setText("" + post.comments_count);


        price.setText("₹" +post.price);
        discountprice.setText("₹" +post.discountprice);
        price.setPaintFlags(price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        button8.setText(post.recipe_time);
        txt_recipe_title.setText(post.recipe_title);
        txt_recipe_time.setText(post.recipe_time);

        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RECIPES_VIEW_COUNT) {
            txt_total_views.setText(Tools.withSuffix(post.total_views) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.views_count));
        } else {
            lyt_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (post.content_type != null && post.content_type.equals("Post")) {
            thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_VIEW_COUNT) {
            btnView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_total_views.setText("" + Tools.withSuffix(post.total_views));
        } else {
            btnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        

        recipe_description.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        recipe_description.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        recipe_description.setFocusable(false);
        recipe_description.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

        WebSettings webSettings = recipe_description.getSettings();
        Resources res = getResources();
        int fontSize = res.getInteger(R.integer.font_size);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);

        String mimeType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = post.recipe_description;

        String bg_paragraph;
        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #eeeeee;}";
        } else {
            bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000000;}";
        }

        String font_style_default = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/custom_font.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont; font-size: medium; text-align: left;}</style>";

        String text = "<html><head>"
                + font_style_default
                + "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> "
                + bg_paragraph
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        String text_rtl = "<html dir='rtl'><head>"
                + font_style_default
                + "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> "
                + bg_paragraph
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        if (RTL_MODE) {
            recipe_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text_rtl, mimeType, encoding, null);
        } else {
            recipe_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
        }
        addToFavorite();
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> lyt_suggested.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), 1000);

    }

    private void displaySuggested(List<Recipe> list) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_suggested);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

        AdapterSuggested adapterSuggested = new AdapterSuggested(ActivityRecipeDetail1.this, recyclerView, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterSuggested);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        adapterSuggested.setOnItemClickListener((view, obj, position) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityRecipeDetail1.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC, obj);
            startActivity(intent);
            adsManager.showInterstitialAd();
        });

        TextView txt_suggested = findViewById(R.id.txt_suggested);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            txt_suggested.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_suggested));
        } else {
            txt_suggested.setText("");
        }

    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarDark));
        } else {
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

        txt_category.setText(post.category_name);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void initFavorite() {
        List<Recipe> data = databaseHandler.getFavRow(post.recipe_id);
        if (data.size() == 0) {
            image_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav_outline);
        } else {
            if (data.get(0).getRecipe_id() == recipe_id) {
                image_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addToFavorite() {

        image_favorite.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            List<Recipe> data1 = databaseHandler.getFavRow(post.recipe_id);
            if (data1.size() == 0) {
                databaseHandler.AddtoFavorite(new Recipe(
                        post.category_name,
                        post.recipe_id,
                        post.recipe_title,
                        post.recipe_time,
                        post.price,
                        post.discountprice,
                        post.recipe_image,
                        post.recipe_description,
                        post.video_url,
                        post.video_id,
                        post.content_type,
                        post.featured,
                        post.tags,
                        post.total_views
                ));
                Snackbar.make(parent_view, R.string.favorite_added, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                image_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);
            } else {
                if (data1.get(0).getRecipe_id() == recipe_id) {


                    databaseHandler.RemoveFav(new Recipe(post.recipe_id));
                    Snackbar.make(parent_view, R.string.favorite_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    image_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav_outline);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void updateView(long nid) {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = RestAdapter.createAPI(sharedPref.getApiUrl());
        Call<Value> call = apiInterface.updateView1(nid);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Value> call, @NonNull Response<Value> response) {
                Value data = response.body();
                if (data != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "View counter updated +" + data.value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Value> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void loadViewed() {
        if (Tools.isConnect(this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/api/api.php?get_total_views3&id=" + post.recipe_id);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return Tools.getJSONString(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                Log.d("TAG", "no data found!");
            } else {

                try {

                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");
                    JSONObject objJson = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }



    private void requestPostApi2() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = RestAdapter.createAPI(sharedPref.getApiUrl());
        callbackCall2 = apiInterface.getUser(myApplication.getUserId());
        callbackCall2.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CallbackUser> call, @NonNull Response<CallbackUser> response) {
                CallbackUser resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.status.equals("ok")) {
                    user = resp.response;
                    sharebutton();
                } else {
                    onFailRequest();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CallbackUser> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            }

        });
    }




    public void onDestroy() {
        if (!(callbackCall == null || callbackCall.isCanceled())) {
            this.callbackCall.cancel();
        }
        lyt_shimmer.stopShimmer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void sharebutton() {
        String wallpaperUrl =BASE_IMAGE_URL + post.recipe_image;
        String wallpaperName = post.recipe_title.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") + "_" + post.id;

        btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {
                if (!myApplication.getIsLogin()) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityUserLogin.class));

                } else {

                    if (!verifyPermissions()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    shareWallpaper(progressDialog, wallpaperName, wallpaperUrl);
                }
            }



        });
    }


    public void shareWallpaper(ProgressDialog progressDialog, String imageName, String imageURL) {

        progressDialog.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.msg_preparing_wallpaper));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Glide.with(this)
                .download(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
                .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        try {

                            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(resource));
                            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);

                            if (mimeType.equals("image/gif")) {
                                setAction(this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageName + ".gif"), SHARE);
                            } else if (mimeType.equals("image/png")) {
                                Tools.setAction(getApplicationContext(), Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageName + ".png"), SHARE);
                            } else {
                                setAction(this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageName + ".jpg"), SHARE);
                            }

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .submit(), DELAY_SET);
    }



    public void setAction( ActivityRecipeDetail1 this, RequestListener<File> requestListener, byte[] bytes, String imgName, String action ) {
        try {
            File dir;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + this.getString(R.string.app_name));
            } else {
                dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + this.getString(R.string.app_name));
            }
            boolean success = true;
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                success = dir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                File imageFile = new File(dir, imgName);
                FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                fileWriter.write(bytes);
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();

                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                File file = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

                switch (action) {


                    case SHARE:
                        String share_title = android.text.Html.fromHtml(post.recipe_title).toString();
                        String share_price = android.text.Html.fromHtml("price:" + post.discountprice).toString();
                        String share_Address = android.text.Html.fromHtml("Address:" + user.Address).toString();
                        String share_pincode = android.text.Html.fromHtml("PinCode:" + user.PinCode).toString();
                        String share_Distict = android.text.Html.fromHtml("State:" + user.State).toString();
                        String title = share_title + "\n\n" + share_price + "\n\n" + share_Address + "\n\n" + share_pincode + "\n\n" + share_Distict + "\n\n";
                        String toNumber = "+918072006997"; // contains spaces.
                        toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "");
                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
                        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);
                        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
                        this.startActivity(sendIntent);
                        break;
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    


}


Please show code and explain what you trying to do.

@Morrison Chang  check bro code

While English may not be your first language, just adding your entire code base without explaining what each part is supposed to do is unhelpful. Please state how the code is supposed to work, what does work and where does it break.

@Morrison Chang  i have send image wattsapp i could not send wattsapp  EACCES (Permission denied) Errors are coming

Setting a bounty won't improve the quality of the question, which does not even tell which API level this is and nobody cares about pages of messy code, which does not constitute a minimal, reproducible example. Likely you just don't have requested permisson to read there.

This question is similar to: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

' /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ ' From Android 10 this path is private path, you can't read data from there. You need to put your file on public directory and read from there.
follow below links:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage/scoped#:~:text=Android%2010%20enforced%20scoped%20storage,using%20a%20direct%20file%20path.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

add the following code in your AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>

You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases
